# Multi-page equation with only a single equation number

Tags: equations, page-breaking

I understand that environments such as `equation` would not allow page break while `align` will.

But I want an equation box that only comes with one equation number and it spans over multiple pages. How do I do that?

Comment: \allowdisplaybreaks in preamble combined with eg multline or gather+ aligned environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with a new environment, where you just specify the line where you want the equation number:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a6paper,textheight=4cm]{geometry} % just for the example
\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\makeatletter
\newcounter{longaligned}
\newenvironment{longaligned}[1][]
 {%
  \stepcounter{longaligned}%
  \refstepcounter{equation}%
  \label{longaligned@\thelongaligned}%
  #1%
  \start@align\@ne\st@rredtrue\m@ne % start align*
 }
 {\endalign}
\newcommand{\longalignedtag}{\tag{\ref{longaligned@\thelongaligned}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{longaligned}
a &=b \\
c &= a+b \\
d &= h+u+j+k \\
r +e &= t + e+ r + r\\
a &=b \\
c &= a+b \\
d &= h+u+j+k \\
r +e &= t + e+ r + r\longalignedtag\\
a &=b \\
c &= a+b \\
d &= h+u+j+k \\
r +e &= t + e+ r + r
\end{longaligned}

\end{document}
```

It's easy to manually adjust the position of one command, than using several `\notag` commands; the disadvantage is that this requires two steps for synchronization, but it shouldn't be a real problem.

[image]

A different solution based on the same idea:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a6paper,textheight=4cm]{geometry} % just for the example
\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\makeatletter
\newcounter{longaligned}
\newenvironment{longaligned}
 {%
  \stepcounter{longaligned}%
  \refstepcounter{equation}%
  \label{longaligned@\thelongaligned}%
  #1%
  \par\textbf{Equation block \eqref{longaligned@\thelongaligned}}
  \start@align\@ne\st@rredtrue\m@ne % start align*
 }
 {\endalign}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{longaligned}
a &=b \\
c &= a+b \\
d &= h+u+j+k \\
r +e &= t + e+ r + r\\
a &=b \\
c &= a+b \\
d &= h+u+j+k \\
r +e &= t + e+ r + r\\
a &=b \\
c &= a+b \\
d &= h+u+j+k \\
r +e &= t + e+ r + r
\end{longaligned}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer, you can easily add “End of equation block” at the bottom.

In both cases, calling the environment as

```
\begin{longaligned}[\label{xyz}]
```

will allow to use `\eqref{xyz}` for referring to the block.

Answer (score 3):

You can use lot of `\notag` s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\textheight}{4cm}  %% just for this example
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
      a &=b \notag\\
      c &= a+b \notag\\
      d &= h+u+j+k \notag\\
      r +e &= t + e+ r + r\notag\\
      a &=b \notag\\
      c &= a+b \notag\\
      d &= h+u+j+k \notag\\
      r +e &= t + e+ r + r\\
      a &=b \notag\\
      c &= a+b \notag\\
      d &= h+u+j+k \notag\\
      r +e &= t + e+ r + r\notag
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But this is not a good idea to have many equations spanning more than one page with one equation number. Have some mercy on the readers.

Comment: It's for derivations that spans for more than a page. It wouldn't be appropriate to assign multiple equation numbers. And I am writing a report, where I am instructed to give a number to each and whatever equation block.

Comment: Btw, if `align` is the solution, why not use `align*` and apply a single `label`?

Comment: @Argyll: You can use anything appropriate. Mine was a blind shot as I had no idea of the nature of the equation/s. With `align*`, you have to step up the equation counter yourself.

Comment: Or just use `align*` and a suitably crafted `\tag`. Exercise for the reader. `;-)`